# Python Save rest of line after string in doc

Tags: python-2.7, variables, readlines

I have a word doc named a.doc formatted:

Name - Bob

Hair color - Red

Age - 28
...

I'd like to save the information after "Name - " "Hair color - " ... into a variable for access later in the script. Would the easiest way be to create a list:

```
Keywords = (Name, 'Hair color', Age)
Fileopen = open(a.doc)
    Filecontent = readlines(fileopen)
        For keywords in filecontent:
```

This is where I get stuck. I'm thinking I can add a statement allowing to grab after the " - " in each line.

EDIT:
To be more precise in my explanation of what I am looking to do:
I would like to grab the information in each line separately after the ' - 
' and store it in a variable. For example Name - Bob will be stored in name equaling 'Bob'.

I have made some progress here since my previous update.  I just know the way I am doing it does not allow for easily repeating.

I have successfully pulled the information utilizing:

```
filename = raw_input("choose your file: ")
print "you chose: %r" % filename
with open(filename) as fo:
    for line in fo:
        if "Name" in line: name = line.split(" - ", 1)[1]
print name
fo.close()
```

I know that I can continue to make a new 'if' statement for each of my strings I'd like to pull, but obviously that isn't the fastest way.

My REAL question:
How to make that if statement into a loop that will check for multiple strings and assign them to separate variables?

In the end I am really just looking to use these variables and reorder the way they are printed out which is why I need them separated.  I attempted to use the 'keywords' but am not sure how to allow that to dynamically define each to a variable that I would like. Should I add them to a list or a tuple and subsequently call upon them in that manner? The variable name obviously has no meaning outside the program so if I called it from a tuple as in [0], that might work as well.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you want to store. Are you looking to store both the key "Hair color" and its value "Red"? If yes, then a dictionary may be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

This code asks for the name, age, and hair color of the person, then returns the person's information while storing the information in the variable Filecontent and is stored until you close the shell:

```
def namesearch(Name, Hair, Age):
Keywords = ('Name - ' + Name + ', Hair Color - ' + Hair \
         + ', Age - ' + Age)
Fileopen = open('a.doc', 'r')
for line in Fileopen:
    if Keywords in line:
        global Filecontent
        Filecontent = line
        print line

Name = raw_input('Enter the person\'s name: ')
Hair = raw_input('Enter the person\'s hair color: ')
Age = raw_input('Enter the person\'s age: ')
namesearch(Name, Hair, Age)
```

This code returns the information in this format:
Name - (Name), Hair Color - (Hair Color), Age - (Age).
Note: This code can only search for names, not add them